# How do I print out each character from a text file

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, console-application, text-files, maze

I have got a text file with a Maze Ascii pattern inside it and I want to be able to retrieve the [x,y] position of the Maze Ascii.

What I'm aiming for is to create a Maze Game with a Player that is drawn outside of the text file and I want to be able to move my player about the Maze ASCII but, in order for me to do that I need to be able to have access to each x,y position of the maze ascii to set my cursor position to those co-ordinates.

The code below is what I have at the moment it is another level to my Maze game. It stores the text file as a variable called 'path'. A string called lines is created with reads all the lines of the text file. then the for loop prints out each line of the text file.

How would I print out each character/element of the text file instead printing out each line? I want to be able to retrieve the x and y position of the text file. Not sure how to do this. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

```
public static void Level2()
        {
            var path = @"C:\Level2.txt";
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);
            foreach(string line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Create a new two-dimensional array.
Push line.ToCharArray() into the array, done. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-5.0

Afterwards you can simply access it by myCharArray[x][y], just make sure that x and y is in the boundaries of the array

Comment: For what it's worth, _render_ is a better verb here than _print out_. Because you posted some code, we were all able to understand your question, but _to print out_ tends to imply rendering something on a printer. In your case, you are rendering some ASCII art to the console. Something to remember

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully, the logic below if helpful to you in trying to print out each designated character inside a text file

```
//read all lines of the file into an array

//declare a Boolean variable to track if the user/password exists

//foreach string in the array

  //split the line on comma and store in an array X

 //Then print each char using .char on the x array
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `string` is also a collection of `char`acters.

You can split each line with, for example, `ToCharArray`:

```
string s = 
@"abc
def";
File.WriteAllText("maze.txt", s);

var maze = File.ReadLines("maze.txt")
          .Select( l => l.ToCharArray())
          .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(maze[1][2]); // 2nd line, 3rd character - 'f'
```